# My VBA is only transferring the last row of Data even though other rows meet Criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have three worksheets that I am working with: 
"Doors" which is the one that must match the criteria, "Jobs" it takes some values off here if criteria is met and "Productions Schedule" where the data is transferred to.

So the criteria is that each row on "Doors" is check that the date is equal to or greater than today's date. If it is then data from specific columns & sheets are then transferred onto "Production Schedule" from Row 24 and down.

The data is transferring correctly other than the fact that it is only taking the last used row from "Doors" not *all* rows that meet the criteria. How do I fix this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Initialize()
   Dim SourceJ As Worksheet, SourceD As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet
   Set SourceJ = Worksheets("Jobs")
   Set SourceD = Worksheets("Doors")
   Set Target = Worksheets("Production Schedule")
   Dim LR As Long
   Dim r As Long
   LR = SourceD.Range("A" & SourceD.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
   Dim tLR As Long
   Dim tr As Long
   tLR = Target.Range("A" & Target.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
     For r = 1 To LR
     If SourceD.Cells(r, 6).Value >= Date Then
        For tr = 24 To tLR
         Target.Cells(tr, 1).Value = SourceD.Cells(r, 5).Value
         Target.Cells(tr, 5).Value = SourceD.Cells(r, 4).Value
         Target.Cells(tr, 6).Value = SourceD.Cells(r, 3).Value
        Next
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value of `tr` is whole the time the same. If I understand your expectations well, the following code should work better:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Initialize()
    Dim SourceJ As Worksheet, SourceD As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim tLR As Long
    Dim tr As Long

    Set SourceJ = Worksheets("Jobs")
    Set SourceD = Worksheets("Doors")
    Set Target = Worksheets("Production Schedule")
    LR = SourceD.Range("A" & SourceD.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    tLR = Target.Range("A" & Target.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    tr = 24
    For r = 1 To LR
        If SourceD.Cells(r, 6).Value >= Date Then
            Target.Cells(tr, 1).Value = SourceD.Cells(r, 5).Value
            Target.Cells(tr, 5).Value = SourceD.Cells(r, 4).Value
            Target.Cells(tr, 6).Value = SourceD.Cells(r, 3).Value
            tr = tr + 1
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That's working perfectly. Thank you @Limak and lots tidier too! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are copying to the same `tr` rows for each iteration of `r`. Did you mean to use "row 24" as an *offset*? For example,

```
For r = 2 To LR
    If SourceD.Cells(r, 6).Value >= Date Then
        For tr = 24 To tLR
            Target.Cells((tLR - 24 + 1) * r + tr - 24, 1).Value = SourceD.Cells(r, 5).Value
            Target.Cells((tLR - 24 + 1) * r + tr - 24, 5).Value = SourceD.Cells(r, 4).Value
            Target.Cells((tLR - 24 + 1) * r + tr - 24, 6).Value = SourceD.Cells(r, 3).Value
        Next
    End If
Next
```

That would guarantee that each row `r` has its own set of Production Schedule rows.

Comment: Thanks @RobertColumbia. It is transferring each row individually now! However it is transferring the last row twice. For "row 24" that is the first row it can enter into. "row 23" has headings. I have also changed For r = 1 To LR to 2 To LR as it was picking up the column headers.

Comment: I updated my answer. How would that work? If it is still slightly off, then let me know what is happening or you can try to fiddle with the arithmetic slightly by adding or subtracting one.

Comment: Thanks for your help @RobertColumbia. Limak has solved it with the way he has used 'tr'.

Comment: @ RobertColumbia, Is it possible to get this macro to run not only when the worksheet is initialized but also whenever there is any change within the whole workbook? Or am I best to create a Sub Workbook_Change () macro with the exact same code?